# UIButton not calling action function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a button created programmatically but for some strange reason when pressed it it doesn't activate the action. There are a few buttons, I've eliminated the other buttons form the code, here is the button that isn't working:

```
struct Buttons {

 var hintButton: UIButton!
 let hintBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 70, height: 70))
 init() {hintBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    hintBtn.tag = 2
    hintBtn.setTitle("Hint", forState: .Normal)
    hintBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    hintButton = hintBtn
}
```

}
Here is the code in the viewController:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        AddAllGraphics()
        ButtonActions()
       self.buttons.hintBtn.enabled = true
    }

     func AddAllGraphics() {
    self.view.addSubview(buttons.hintBtn)
}

    func ButtonActions() {
      buttons.hintBtn.addTarget(self, action: "giveHint:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

     func giveHint(sender:UIButton) {
        if(sender.tag == 2){
          buttons.hintBtn.enabled = false
          print("It Works")
        }
      }
```

I've tried putting a break point at the "giveHint" function but it is never called when the button is pressed. I've tried putting self.buttons.btn.userInteractionEnabled = true in the viewDidLoad but it still doesn't work.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you check to see if buttons.hintBtn is valid or not?

Comment: What do you mean by making sure it's valid?

Comment: The same object as the one you created.  Not nil or some different object.

Comment: I tried if buttons.hintBtn == nil { print"nil"}  but I got an error UIButton can never be nil

Answer (score 0):

The code above is working for me, but I had to init the struct properly:

```
struct Buttons {
var hintButton: UIButton!
let hintBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 70, height: 70))
init() {
    hintBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    hintBtn.tag = 2
    hintBtn.setTitle("Hint", forState: .Normal)
    hintBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    hintButton = hintBtn
}
}
```

Comment: Whoops, forgot to put the init in the code I posted.  It's there in the actual code but the action still isn't being called.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue. The button was behind another view that had user interaction disabled. Since the view was clear I thought I was pressing the button.